# Database replication not working properly for one forest

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have database replication setup, connect-forest-with-name is set to true. The whole system has got 3 clusters - one master and 2 replicas. I have 6 forests in each cluster. 5 out of 6 forests are fine. But for the remaining forest on both the replica clusters, the state continues to be syncing replica but the number of documents or fragments are not changing at all.

When I had a look at the logs, I got something related to replication lag. Here are the logs which I am getting -

- Master

> ```
> 2017-02-14 14:20:56.966 Info: Forest forest-4 needs to replicate 199894 fragments [0:0..1205099690503950842:222485256415483574] to foreign forest forest-4 in cluster replica-1-1-cluster
> 2017-02-14 14:20:57.002 Info: Forest forest-4 needs to replicate 199894 fragments [0:0..1205099690503950842:222485256415483574] to foreign forest forest-4 in cluster replica-2-1-cluster
> ```

- Replica-1

> ```
> 2017-02-14 14:43:54.911 Info: Forest forest-4 received 1000000 replication timestamps start at 0/0 more coming true from foreign forest forest-4 in cluster master-1-cluster
> 2017-02-14 14:43:55.022 Info: Forest forest-4 finished replicating timestamps master-only=199894 replica-only=0 timestamp-right=800106 timestamp-wrong=0 duplicate=0 more-coming=true
> ```

- Replica-2

> ```
> 2017-02-14 14:47:01.298 Info: Forest forest-4 received 1000000 replication timestamps start at 0/0 more coming true from foreign forest forest-4 in cluster master-1-cluster
> 2017-02-14 14:47:01.410 Info: Forest forest-4 finished replicating timestamps master-only=199894 replica-only=0 timestamp-right=800106 timestamp-wrong=0 duplicate=0 more-coming=true
> ```

I have tried few things like -

- Restarting clusters and forests
- Detach and attach the forest again
- Clearing data of forest and let it replicate again

Can someone help me in understanding why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: I would wireshark or other network analysis tool to watch traffic and see if you are seeing network issues.  I've seen behavior similar to this when network cards are not working correctly.